rolling weighted mean by group with zoo and dplyr
I need to calculate the moving, weighted average by group in R.
Below is a sample of my code:
df %>% 
arrange(Type, Year)
group_by(Type) %>% 
mutate(
"weighted.rolling.mean" = rollapplyr(
    df %>% select(Value, Area),
    width = 50,
    function(z){
      return(
        weighted_mean = weighted.mean(z[,"Value"],z[,"Area"], partial = TRUE)
      )
    },
    by.column = FALSE,
    align = "right",
    fill=NA
  )
)

Without the group_by argument, the code works fine.
If I group_by inside the rollapplyr function, I get the error below:
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `weighted.rolling.mean = rollapplyr(...)`.
ℹ In group 1: `Type = "Etageadskillelse"`.
Caused by error in `x * w`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator
Backtrace:
  1. ... %>% ...
  9. zoo::rollapplyr(...)
 11. zoo:::rollapply.default(..., align = align)
 14. zoo:::rollapply.zoo(zoo(data), ...)
 15. base::mapply(...)
 16. zoo (local) `<fn>`(dots[[1L]][[50L]], dots[[2L]][[50L]], data = `<chr[,4]>`)
 17. FUN(data[posns, ], ...)
 19. stats:::weighted.mean.default(z[, "Value"], z[, "Area"], partial = TRUE)

Many thanks in advance!
Update
Here's an example of my dataset:
structure(list(Value = c(0.55, 0.14, 0.760367571281347, 0.25, 
0.4, 0.12, 0.4, 0.13, 0.14, 0.344161801501251, 1.06, 0.58, 0.45, 
0.68, 0.36, 0.19, 0.25, 0.68, 0.08, 0.14, 1.74386666666667, 0.3, 
0.350285714285714, 0.07, 0.14), Area = c(3.5, 11.2, 87.33, 133, 
16.67, 112.3, 44, 281, 121, 119.9, 77, 82, 33.48, 102.1, 98.07, 
121.53, 54, 2.15, 15.48, 136, 30, 31.5, 70, 144.15, 100), Type = c("Ydervæg", 
"Kvist", "Ydervæg", "Ydervæg", "Ydervæg", "Loft", "Skunk", 
"Loft", "Loft", "Ydervæg", "Ydervæg", "Etageadskillelse", "Terrændæk", 
"Ydervæg", "Ydervæg", "Loft", "Loft", "Ydervæg", "Terrændæk", 
"Loft", "Etageadskillelse", "Terrændæk", "Skunk", "Terrændæk", 
"Loft"), Year = c(1965L, 2011L, 1966L, 1929L, 1890L, 1937L, 1926L, 
1846L, 1965L, 1920L, 1963L, 1936L, 1947L, 1920L, 1973L, 1967L, 
1915L, 1814L, 1964L, 2005L, 1950L, 1933L, 1929L, 1874L, 1964L
)), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))


Please provide some data, e.g. dput(head(df)).

There's perhaps a few problems here - one being that I think your Area or Value columns might not be numeric? Within rollapplyr it's converting it to a zoo object and might be making all columns characters.

Use pick rather than select, partial is misplaced, ensure that the argument passed to FUN is a matrix, use rollapplyr with an r on the end to avoid the need for align = "right". The question has not provided enough data to use a width of 50 so we used a width of 3.
df %>% 
  arrange(Type, Year) %>%
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  mutate("weighted.rolling.mean" = rollapplyr(
    pick(Value, Area),
    width = 3,
    FUN = \(z, m = matrix(z, ncol = 2)) weighted.mean(m[,1], m[,2]),
    by.column = FALSE,
    fill=NA,
    partial = TRUE
  )
)

giving
# A tibble: 25 × 5
# Groups:   Type [6]
   Value  Area Type              Year weighted.rolling.mean
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>            <int>                 <dbl>
 1  0.58  82   Etageadskillelse  1936                 0.58 
 2  1.74  30   Etageadskillelse  1950                 0.892
 3  0.14  11.2 Kvist             2011                 0.14 
 4  0.13 281   Loft              1846                 0.13 
 5  0.25  54   Loft              1915                 0.149
 6  0.12 112.  Loft              1937                 0.142
 7  0.14 100   Loft              1964                 0.154
 8  0.14 121   Loft              1965                 0.133
 9  0.19 122.  Loft              1967                 0.158
10  0.14 136   Loft              2005                 0.156
# ℹ 15 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows


Works perfectly, thank you! Could you perhaps be so kind to explain the semantics in the FUN-argument (or point me in a direction of a reference)? I dont' understand the '(z, m = matrix(z, ncol = 2))'-part.

This is the same as \(x) { m <- matrix(z, ncol = 2); weighted.mean(m[,1], m[,2]) }  By putting m as an argument the body becomes one line so we don't need { and }.  The need for matrix(...) is due to the use of partial=TRUE which will send a vector rather than matrix to the function when there is only one time point. If we omit partial=TRUE then it will always send a matrix so the matrix part is not needed.

In base R you could do the following:
fn <- function(x, n){
  i <- embed(c(rep(NA, n-1), x[[1]]), n)
  j <- embed(c(rep(NA, n-1), x[[2]]), n)
  rowSums(i*j, na.rm = TRUE)/rowSums(j, na.rm = TRUE)
}

transform(sort_by(df, ~Type + Year),
  result = unlist(by(list(Value, Area), Type, fn, 3), use.names = FALSE))



     Value   Area             Type Year    result
1  0.5800000  82.00 Etageadskillelse 1936 0.5800000
2  1.7438667  30.00 Etageadskillelse 1950 0.8917500
3  0.1400000  11.20            Kvist 2011 0.1400000
4  0.1300000 281.00             Loft 1846 0.1300000
5  0.2500000  54.00             Loft 1915 0.1493433
6  0.1200000 112.30             Loft 1937 0.1419763
7  0.1400000 100.00             Loft 1964 0.1538716
8  0.1400000 121.00             Loft 1965 0.1332613
9  0.1900000 121.53             Loft 1967 0.1577401
10 0.1400000 136.00             Loft 2005 0.1560529
11 0.4000000  44.00            Skunk 1926 0.4000000
12 0.3502857  70.00            Skunk 1929 0.3694737
13 0.0700000 144.15        Terrændæk 1874 0.0700000
14 0.3000000  31.50        Terrændæk 1933 0.1112468
15 0.4500000  33.48        Terrændæk 1947 0.1654784
16 0.0800000  15.48        Terrændæk 1964 0.3200895
17 0.6800000   2.15          Ydervæg 1814 0.6800000
18 0.4000000  16.67          Ydervæg 1890 0.4319872
19 0.3441618 119.90          Ydervæg 1920 0.3560770
20 0.6800000 102.10          Ydervæg 1920 0.4917292
21 0.2500000 133.00          Ydervæg 1929 0.4054732
22 1.0600000  77.00          Ydervæg 1963 0.5905095
23 0.5500000   3.50          Ydervæg 1965 0.5470492
24 0.7603676  87.33          Ydervæg 1966 0.8934511
25 0.3600000  98.07          Ydervæg 1973 0.5486136

